# Do drifters age?

Tags: drifters

Count Saint Germi is regarded as one of the founding fathers of Orte and was also the first member of the aristocracy to side with [Adolf Hitler](https://drifters.fandom.com/wiki/Adolf_Hitler) in creating the Empire and that was 60 years ago. How was he able to live fo so long and not age a bit? Is this a characteristic of all Drifters? or just an ability exclusive to Germi.